# How can i convert my AS3 keyboard events into mouse events?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, onclicklistener, movieclip, keyboard-events

I would like to keep my keyboard events but add mouse events to work as well.
My game keyboard events work fine I just can't get my head round how to add the mouse events to them.

I have some movieclips on my stage left right up down etc.

```
Character.as

[code]
if( m_keyboard.IsKeyDown( eKeyCodes.kLeftArrow ) )
{
    walking = true;
    x += 1;
    this.scaleX = 1;    
}

if( m_keyboard.IsKeyDown( eKeyCodes.kRightArrow ) )
etc....
[code]

eKeyCodes.as

[code]
static public const kLeftArrow:int = 37;
static public const kRightArrow:int = 39;

etc....
[/code]

Keyboard.as
[/code]
public class Keyboard
{
    private const kNumKeyCodes:int = 255;

    private var m_liveKeyState:Vector.<Boolean>;
    private var m_keyState:Vector.<Boolean>;
    private var m_lastKeyState:Vector.<Boolean>;

    public function Keyboard( stage:Stage )
    {
        // add handlers
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, OnKeyDown, false, 0, true );
        stage.addEventListener( KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, OnKeyUp, false, 0, true );

        // vector is an array of booleans , the array is length is passed into the constructor as 255.
        m_keyState = new Vector.<Boolean>( kNumKeyCodes );
        m_lastKeyState = new Vector.<Boolean>( kNumKeyCodes );
        m_liveKeyState = new Vector.<Boolean>( kNumKeyCodes );

        // clear state
        for ( var i:int = 0; i<kNumKeyCodes; i++ )
        {
            // the whole array is false;
            m_keyState[i] = false;
            m_lastKeyState[i] = false;
            m_liveKeyState[i] = false;
        }



    }

    public function Update( ):void
    {

        for ( var i:int = 0; i<kNumKeyCodes; i++ )
        {
            m_lastKeyState[i] = m_keyState[i];
            m_keyState[i] = m_liveKeyState[i];
        }
    }

    private function OnKeyDown( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {

        m_liveKeyState[e.keyCode] = true;
        trace("m_liveKeyState = " + e.keyCode);
    }

    private function OnKeyUp( e:KeyboardEvent ):void
    {

        m_liveKeyState[e.keyCode] = false;
    }

    public function IsKeyDown( key:int ):Boolean           
    {
        // if key is down leftarrow ( 36 ) && 36 < 255 do no error; as key is a valid key;
        Assert( key >= 0 && key <= kNumKeyCodes, "Keyboard.IsKeyDown(): invalid key!" );

        return m_keyState[key];

    }

    /// Is key transitioning 

    public function IsKeyDownTransition( key:int ):Boolean
    {
        Assert( key >= 0 && key <= kNumKeyCodes, "Keyboard.IsKeyDownTransition(): invalid key!" );

        return !m_lastKeyState[key] && m_keyState[key]; 
    }
}
}
[/code]
```

I was thinking something like....

```
TouchButtons.as
[code]
 icon.leftButton.addEventListner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, leftButtonPressed, false, 0, true);
 icon.RightButton.addEventListner(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, rightButtonPressed, false, 0, true);


 public function leftButtonPressed( event:MouseEvent ):void
 {
      m_keyboard.IsKeyDown( eKeyCodes.kLeftArrow  );
 }
 etc...
[code]
```

But That dosn't seem to work, is there an easy way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want it works like stage event.

```
public function leftButtonPressed( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
      m_liveKeyState[eKeyCodes.kLeftArrow] = true;
 }
```

Comment: I will give that a try thanks, I would also need to do eventlisteners for the release of of left and right buttons too wouldn't I ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add eventListeners for other buttons.You may use one event handler function for  all buttons you want and switch event target(buttons) in that function.

Comment: i have wrote four functions for left pressed, left released right pressed, right released, changing the true and false of the liveKeyState, my character does walk left and right but going from left to right quickly causes my character to walk in his own direction even when im not pressing anything, my keyboard code is fine. Im not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Do you mean your character goes faster in using MouseEvent than kerboard? I guess character's walking control if the character should move, so try to debug in character to catch when the walking should be  set to false but haven't when the key is up.

Comment: No i meant that going from left to right fast confuses the direction that it should be going. I will try to debug to see if i notice anything. The speed is the same as the keyboard. Its just that the keyboard is fine going from left to right fast but mouse events are not.

Answer (score 0):

Friend'm going crazy, I wanted to convert this code to use in touch screen

```html
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;

var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
var upBumping:Boolean = false;
var downBumping:Boolean = false;

var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(70, -50);
var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -110);
var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

var scrollX:Number = 0;
var scrollY:Number = 500;

var xSpeed:Number = 0;
var ySpeed:Number = 0;

var speedConstant:Number = 2;
var frictionConstant:Number = 0.9;
var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
var jumpConstant:Number = -30;
var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;

var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(e:Event):void{
 if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
  //trace("leftBumping");
  leftBumping = true;
 } else {
  leftBumping = false;
 }
 
 if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
  //trace("rightBumping");
  rightBumping = true;
 } else {
  rightBumping = false;
 }
 
 if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
  //trace("upBumping");
  upBumping = true;
 } else {
  upBumping = false;
 }
 
 if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
  //trace("downBumping");
  downBumping = true;
 } else {
  downBumping = false;
 } 
 

 if(leftPressed){
  xSpeed -= speedConstant;
  player.scaleX = -1;

 } else if(rightPressed){
  xSpeed += speedConstant;
  player.scaleX = 1;
 }


 if(leftBumping){
  if(xSpeed < 0){
   xSpeed *= -0.5;
  }
 }
 
 if(rightBumping){
  if(xSpeed > 0){
   xSpeed *= -0.5;
  }
 }
 
 if(upBumping){
  if(ySpeed < 0){
   ySpeed *= -0.5;
  }
 }
 
 if(downBumping){ //if we are touching the floor
  if(ySpeed > 0){ 
   ySpeed = 0; //set the y speed to zero
  }
  if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
   ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
  }
  
  //DOUBLE JUMP
  if(upReleasedInAir == true){
   upReleasedInAir = false;
  }
  if(doubleJumpReady == false){
   doubleJumpReady = true;
  }
 } else { //if we are not touching the floor
  
  ySpeed += gravityConstant; //accelerate downwards
  
  //DOUBLE JUMP
  if(upPressed == false && upReleasedInAir == false){
   upReleasedInAir = true;
   //trace("upReleasedInAir");
  }
  if(doubleJumpReady && upReleasedInAir){
   if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
    //trace("doubleJump!");
    doubleJumpReady = false;
    ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
   }
  }
  
 }
 
 if(keyCollected == false){
  if(player.hitTestObject(back.doorKey)){
   back.doorKey.visible = false;
   keyCollected = true;
   trace("key collected");
  }
 }
 
 if(doorOpen == false){
  if(keyCollected == true){
   if(player.hitTestObject(back.lockedDoor)){
    back.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2);
    doorOpen = true;
    trace("door open");
   }
  }
 }
            
 
 if(xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant){ //moving right
  xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
 } else if(xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)){ //moving left
  xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
 }
 
 xSpeed *= frictionConstant;
 ySpeed *= frictionConstant;
 
 if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5){
  xSpeed = 0;
 }
 
 scrollX -= xSpeed;
 scrollY -= ySpeed;

 back.x = scrollX;
 back.y = scrollY;
 
 sky.x = scrollX * 0.2;
 sky.y = scrollY * 0.2;
 
}

function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
  leftPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
  rightPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
  upPressed = true;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = true;
 } 
}

function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
 if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
  leftPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
  rightPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
  upPressed = false;
 
 } else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
  downPressed = false;
 } 
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer and you shouldn't be posting this here. You should post your own question detailing what you are looking for, and what you have tried, and what you have, posting any relevant code as well.